# App Store Connect Distribution Options (Necessary or not?)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, react-native-ios

I am preparing to upload my ipa file to the Appstore through Xcode.

When I click on Product
then choose Archive
then click Distribute App

It then shows me 3 options to check or uncheck:
1.) Include bitcode for iOS content
2.) Strip Swift Symbols
3.) Uplaod your app's symbols to receive symbolicated reports from apple

How necessary are these 3. 
Is it okay if I uncheck all 3?
The reason I'm considering unchecking the 3 of them is because when I click Next with all 3 checked I am getting a error.
I am getting a Copy failed error and I'm guessing this is because of the computer running out of space.  I am using Mac In Cloud and the space is pretty small.....

I just want to be able to publish my App to the Appstore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's okay to uncheck all 3. You'll still be able to publish your app to the App Store.